# pytket compiler pass to shorten all angles by multiples of 2 pi

Tags: programming, pytket

After applying some compiler passes in pytket, I get gates like rx(3.5*pi). Is there a pass that simply shortens the angles by multiples of 2 pi, so that I get rx(1.5*pi) instead?

Comment: Hi there. There's no specific pytket pass but if you like I can perhaps share how to write a pytket `CustomPass` to accomplish this. Out of curiosity, did you have a particular use for this in mind? Or would you just prefer to reduce the angles modulo 2*pi for tidiness?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is no specific reason other than a cleaner look of the created QASM code. I think it will not be difficult to write a CustomPass for this, just wanted to check if there is already a solution I did not find in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Callums feedback I wrote a function for a CustomPass.

```
def shorten_rotations(circ: Circuit) -> Circuit:
    circ_prime = Circuit(circ.n_qubits, circ.n_bits)
    for cmd in circ.get_commands():
        if cmd.op.type in (OpType.Rx, OpType.Ry, OpType.Rz):
            params_prime = cmd.op.params
            params_prime[0] = params_prime[0] % 2
            circ_prime.add_gate(cmd.op.type, params_prime, cmd.qubits)
        elif cmd.op.type == OpType.Measure:
            circ_prime.Measure(cmd.qubits[0].index[0], cmd.bits[0].index[0])
        else:
            circ_prime.add_gate(cmd.op.type, cmd.op.params, cmd.qubits)
    return circ_prime
```

Comment: Nice one, looks good to me :)